# displaying multiple images with Glide without Recycler View

Tags: java, android, android-glide

as the title indicate, how can i display multiple images from a URL array using glide and without using a recycler view? let say i want to use a verticale linear layout.

Comment: It's going backwards on the modern development but it's possible. You could create a loop which add a imageview and attach them to a main layout.

Comment: Is there a reason u do not want to use a recycler view?

Comment: i am working on an app for my final year project and i am running out of time and i dont want an optimal but long and complicated solution. rather , i always seek an easy and short solution even not optimised. my app is not commercial and probably it will run only for one day(the day when i will present it). so i decided to let all optimisation and performances when i finish the basic tasks that the app should do.

Comment: Recycler view are so easy to implement nowadays, a lot of thing it does for itself. Your approach is harder to code and it will consume more time.